# Change Excel Comment Font in C# VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, comments, vsto

This may seem really trivial, but for the life of me I cant figure out how to alter the font properties of a comment box. Excample of VBA code would be:

```
Sub SetCommentsProperties()
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Selection
If Not Cell.Comment Is Nothing Then
With Cell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font
.ColorIndex = 3
.Size = 12
.Name = "Arial Black"
End With
End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

However, in C# VSTO, I can only go as far as

```
Cell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection as Range;
var textFrame = selection.Comment.Shape.TextFrame;
textFrame.Characters().Font.ColorIndex = 3;
textFrame.Characters().Font.Size = 30;
```

You can see all the members of the Characters class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.characters_members(v=office.14).aspx).